# Azure Devops rule to avoid automatically reassigning to original owner of work item

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to configure our Azure DevOps process.
In this regard, I noticed when a work item is changed in the state to Closed/resolved, then it automatically reassigns the ticket to the original owner.

This is expected according to the documentation since this is based on an agile approach.

However, I would like to avoid this and tried with defining custom rules for work items without luck.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: This rule will be removed in Bug in the next Azure DevOps sprint: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/removing-assigned-to-rule-from-bug/

Comment: Hi Mathias, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

As you mentioned above, this is **expected behavior**(reassigning to original owner) for `Agile` process model. As I know Azure Devops doesn't have out-of-box feature to modify the this behavior.

Here're some choices which may help to avoid it:

1.Manually modify the `Assigned to` filed before saving the changes.

If the original user of one WIT was PersonA, and the WIT was then assigned to PersonB, the WIT would be assigned to original PersonA once the stage is changed to Resolved/Closed. But we can manually change the `assigned to` field to PersonB before saving the changes, and it won't be automatically changed to original PersonA after that.

2.Create custom WIT, the `expected behavior` above only works for default work items. So you can create custom work items to avoid the reassigning behavior. (Org settings=>Process=>New WIT type)

[image]

3.Post a feature request on the [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) which is our main forum for product suggestions. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.